# replace zero with index value using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1:

```
    ref   Name   id  Score
4  8400   John    0     12
8  3840  Peter  414      0
15 7400  David  612     64
24 5200  Karen    0      0
```

I want to replace 0 in the **id column** with value of **their index(4,24)** of the same row So it will become:

```
   ref    Name   id   Score
  8400   John  4       12
  3840  Peter  414      0
  7400  David  612     64
  5200  Karen  24      0
```

Then I want to compare it with another df based on id value, So Aafter that i need to remove again the value of the index putted in id. In order to go back to the initial value of **the column id**

**the final output** will be:

```
     ref    Name   id   Score   best_id
      8400   John   0     12    8734
      3840  Peter  414    0    7364
      7400  David  612    64    4367
      5200  Karen   0     0     3467
```

UPDATE: Here is the **df ref**

```
    Name      ID
    John     8734
    Peter   7364
    David    4367
    Karen    3467
```

Comment: Can you give us the "other dataframe" so that we can see where `best_id` comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a new column for what you want using [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

  ```py
  df['new_id'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.id or row.name, axis=1)
  ```
- Use the new column to compare with another.
- Drop the new column using [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) if you don't need it anymore.

  ```py
  df.drop(columns=['new_id'], inplace=True)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be looking at [`df.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)

```
>>> df['id'].mask(df['id'] == 0, df.index.to_series())
4       4
8     414
15    612
24     24
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

You can either then assign that to `df['id']` or pass `inplace=True` to the mask function.